# Uploading file to Dropbox using Spring.Social Dropbox library

Tags: c#, dropbox

I am currently working on a c# project and I am trying to implement dropbox within my program. I have successfully managed to authenticate dropbox and create a directory but I can't work out how to upload a file.

The Dropbox access type is AppFolder and I can create a folder within the app folder. To upload the file, just for a test, I am writing something to a text field and submitting the form, I then write the string to a text file, within the working directory of the executable and I am then trying to upload the file into the root of the app folder, but it is throwing an exception `one more errors have occurred` probably the least useful error.

In case it matters below is how I am authenticating Dropbox.

```
private void authenticateDropbox(Boolean isFromCallBack = false)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!isFromCallBack)
                {
                    dropboxServiceProvider = new DropboxServiceProvider(dropboxAppKey, dropboxAppSecret, AccessLevel.AppFolder);
                    //lblStatus.Content = "Getting request Token";

                    oauthToken = dropboxServiceProvider.OAuthOperations.FetchRequestTokenAsync(callbackUrl, null).Result;
                    //lblStatus.Content = "Request token retrieved";

                    parameters = new OAuth1Parameters();
                    parameters.CallbackUrl = callbackUrl;
                    string authenticateUrl = dropboxServiceProvider.OAuthOperations.BuildAuthorizeUrl(oauthToken.Value, parameters);
                    webDropbox.Navigate(new Uri(authenticateUrl));
                }
                else
                {
                    AuthorizedRequestToken requestToken = new AuthorizedRequestToken(oauthToken, null);
                    OAuthToken oauthAccessToken = dropboxServiceProvider.OAuthOperations.ExchangeForAccessTokenAsync(requestToken, null).Result;

                    Properties.Settings.Default.dropbox_accessSecret = oauthAccessToken.Secret;
                    Properties.Settings.Default.dropbox_accessToken = oauthAccessToken.Value;
                    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

                    IDropbox dropbox = dropboxServiceProvider.GetApi(oauthAccessToken.Value, oauthAccessToken.Secret);

                    DropboxProfile profile = dropbox.GetUserProfileAsync().Result;
                    Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Welcome " + profile.DisplayName, "DropBox Success", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                }
            }
            catch (AggregateException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("AggregateException: Failed to authenticate\n\n" + ex.Message, "Authentication Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("General Exception: Failed to authenticate\n\n" + ex.Message, "Authentication Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }

        private void webDropbox_Navigating(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            string url = e.Uri.ToString();
            if (url.StartsWith(callbackUrl, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                authenticateDropbox(true);
            }
        }
```

Below is the code on how I am creating the directory, which is working, then upload a file

```
private void uploadContentToDropbox()
        {
            try
            {
                DropboxServiceProvider dropboxServiceProvider = new DropboxServiceProvider(dropboxAppKey, dropboxAppSecret, AccessLevel.AppFolder);
                IDropbox dropbox = dropboxServiceProvider.GetApi(Properties.Settings.Default.dropbox_accessToken, Properties.Settings.Default.dropbox_accessSecret);

                //DeltaPage deltaPage = dropbox.DeltaAsync(null).Result;
                writeContentToFile();

                Entry createFolderEntry = dropbox.CreateFolderAsync("Test Folder").Result;

                Entry uploadFileEntry = dropbox.UploadFileAsync(
                    new AssemblyResource("assembly://DropBoxTest/DropBoxTest/upload.txt"), "upload.txt", true, null, CancellationToken.None).Result;
            }
            catch (AggregateException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failed to upload:\n\n" + ex.Message, "Dropbox Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("General failed to upload:\n\n" + ex.Message, "Dropbox Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }
```

I'm not sure if the `uploadFileEntry` is the one that I want as I don't see why I need to say new AssemblyResource as its not a resource of the program it is just a text file that is created.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to find out what to do after hours of trawling through Google, managed to get some luck to find something.

It doesn't need to be an assembly resource, so I instead create the file as I was before but before doing the upload I do the following:

```
var res = new FileResource("upload.txt");
```

And then change the upload to the following:

```
Entry uploadFileEntry = dropbox.UploadFileAsync(
                    res, "upload.txt", true, null, CancellationToken.None).Result;
```

Notice, I'm not doing new AssemblyResource anymore.

Comment: More info about the IResource abstraction here:
http://www.springframework.net/rest/refdoc/http-messageconversion.html#http-resourceconverter

Comment: What library are you using for your project ?